# Bulk import users into SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell, azure

I am looking for an easy way to create logins and associated users into SQL Azure.

The thing is that, with Azure, one first needs to create a login in the master database.
Based on that login I need  a user to be created in a specific database  (`DATABASE1`)

After that roles need to be assigned:

```
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';
CREATE USER login1User FROM LOGIN login1;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'login1User';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'somerole';
```

The thing is, since one cannot use the `USE` command to switch databases, this seems to become quite a tedious task. More so because the number of accounts per database can range from ten to a few hundred, databases and users are being added all the time.

So I need a solution that can be easily reused.

I would like to have a script of some sorts (powershell?) that will read a file (containing username, password and databasename) and then create the appropriate logins, users and rights.....

Icing on the cake would be some sort of job that would regularly check whether there are (new) files present in a certain folder and if so, read those files and create new accounts where needed.

I must admit that I do have TSQL knowledge, basic programming knowledge but no Powershell experience at all. How would you advise that I go about? Is powershell the way to go? Or are there any other mechanisms I could use?

Greetings, Henro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx) you sure can use Powershell from your desktop machine to connect to SQL Database to manage SQL Database account in similar way you would connect to other SQL Server. 
PowerShell scripts can run on an on-premise computer and connect to SQL Database using  System Management Objects or Data-tier Applications Framework object.

The very first step in this direction is to get your Powershell commands connecting to SQL Database and you can use [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3804.how-to-manage-windows-azure-sql-database-servers-using-windows-powershell-en-us.aspx) to get upto here.

After that you just need to use the Powershell script to create users login and searching quickly I found [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2011/06/03/use-powershell-to-add-a-login-to-a-database-role-in-all-databases.aspx) and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/8fbefc94-894c-4b88-b93d-ac360d70a230) promising which includes a few more functionalities along with your objective. You may need to tweak script to make it working with SQL database.

Finally you can search internet to read data form a file (or XML to be better) and feed user info to your SQL Database script. If you have any issue in between step, open specific question and you will be helped.

Comment: Avkash, this looks very promising! I will dive into it a bit deeper on monday. Where and how did you find these articles?  (just wondering why I hadn't found them myselves)